# Why I get Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing while data is returned successfully

Tags: jquery, ajax, nginx, cors

I know this question has been asked tons of times in `SO` but this problem is totally different!

As [`Mozilla` itself says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin) about the header, you have to set this like below in `nginX`:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'origin-list'
```

I have set the `CORS` options and the interesting part is that `preflight request` succeeds:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Type,Accept,authorization,Expires,Pragma,x-custom-header
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000
```

[image]

The endpoint is `/user`. Now the actual `GET` request is sent to server and again it succeeds with `200` response code `JSON` payload it expected!

[image]

The problem resides in the part that I want to get this data from within `jQuery` like below:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url_endpoint,
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _TOKEN);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (data, stat) { 
            console.log('got error data: ', stat);
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function(xhr, data) {
            console.log('here is the data...', data, xhr);
        }
    }).catch(function(data,x,y) {
        console.log(data,x,y,'it seems request has error!!!!');
    });
```

It logs the error parts of the request like inside of `catch` and in console I see the below error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.example.com/restapi/user. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).[Learn More]

It displays that the header is missing while I explain that headers are returned in `OPTIONS`. To make sure this error relates to this specific request I commented out the `/user` request and error of `CORS` gone.

Why I get `CORS` while server response 204 for `OPTIONS` and why I get `CORS` while json response is returned for `/user`

Comment: Are you certain your call is coming from `localhost:3000`? Have you tried `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` just to test to ensure the CORS headers are working at all?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I'd expect that if the `OPTIONS` call weren't from an allowed origin, the browser wouldn't even make the `GET`. But it is in the OP's example.

Comment: It's nice to see a *good* CORS question...

Comment: That's true. To both comments :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes I set it to `'*'` and it gives `*` in `OPTIONS` response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CORS headers must **also** accompany the response to the `GET`, not just the response to the `OPTIONS`. E.g., you send them twice (if there's a preflight).